# How does crashlytics' crash method work?

Tags: ios, crash, crashlytics

How does the `[[Crashlytics sharedInstance] crash];` crash the app? At their [homepage](http://support.crashlytics.com/knowledgebase/articles/92522-is-there-a-quick-way-to-force-a-crash) they advice some good ways to crash the app, but does the `crash` method use one of them?

Comment: As the linked webpage says: "Divide-by-zero is illegal on i386 and x84-64, but is a valid operation on ARM!  Dividing by zero will cause crashes in the simulator, but not on iOS devices."

Comment: If you call the method and crash you will see that it calls an assembly instruction with an invalid opcode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need make crash for Crashlitycs test you can write this code:

```
[someObject performSelector:@selector(abrakadabra:)];
```